# Cast AActor to IGenericTeamAgentInterface | GetTeamAttitudeTowards

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I want to implement/overwrite

```
virtual ETeamAttitude::Type GetTeamAttitudeTowards(const AActor& Other)
```

in my controller. For that I need the opponents team id.
For that I cast AActor& Other to check if it imlements the IGenericTeamAgentInterface.

```
const IGenericTeamAgentInterface* TeamAgent = Cast<IGenericTeamAgentInterface>(&Other);
```

But that returns something that is not true even if my Base unit inherits that interface.

Comment: Have you tried Cast<IGenericTeamAgentInterface>(Other); ? Not sure if it needs to be passed by reference.

Comment: Thank you but not working: no instance of overloaded 'Cast' matches argument list. Argument Types are (const AACtor)

Comment: What is the error you are getting originally? You say "that returns something that is not true" but what do you meen? Is TeamAgent NULL? Are you getting a compile error?

Comment: I get no compile error orgnialy, but something that evaluates to false (cannot check right now) since it is not returning true that would mean Other is not implementing that interface, buuuut since every actor I use in that scene inherits from a baseActor I implemented and that actor does implement that interface

Comment: Cast will return null if it cant cast to that class successfully (false on what your saying). Are you sure you are implementing any and all pure virtual and abstract functions in the base class AND implement the functions from the interface in the child class?

Comment: I will check that later. But what do you mean: cast returns null if it canot cast and false if interface is not implemented, when does casting returns null, in which cases espacaly?

Comment: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/40599-casting-c-syntax-and-ue-syntax

Comment: That explains the difference between manual casting and using the Cast UE4 method but not when the method returns null and false. If I get the Epic wiki working I will check that

Comment: The result is equal to: NULL, nullptr|0, false

Comment: "mplementing any and all pure virtual and abstract functions in the base class AND implement the functions from the interface in the child class" @Katianie Do I have to reimplement them in every child class`? That sounds not like OOP.

Comment: @Katianie Do you want to add you comment (the one I upped) as an answer so I can mark it as the solution. I forgot to add the 'virtual' keyword for the overriden methods in the base class. It seems to work now the return value is not null anymore (i dont know if the teaming stuff works but I can work now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast will return null if it cant cast to that class successfully (false on what your saying). Are you sure you are implementing any and all pure virtual and abstract functions in the base class AND implement the functions from the interface in the child class?